# NPSP errors on creating new contact?

Tags: npsp

I've got an org with 100,000+ contact records. We recently started seeing an issue where new contact creation fails if any of the Address fields are filled in. We recieve the following error:

```
Review all error messages below to correct your data. 
Non-selective query against large object type (more than 100000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or 
contact salesforce.com about custom indexing. Even if a field is indexed a filter might still not be 
selective when: 1. The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null) 2. 
Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for instance, filtering for a 
particular foreign key value that occurs many times)
```

We don't have any other triggers that fire on Contact records, so could this be a bug within the NPSP? Debugging is tough, since I don't seem to get any info about why, or in what package the error has occured!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the answer. NPSP 3.0 had an error in the way it assigned Addresses to Accounts. This has already been corrected in a hotfix put out by the NPSP team. See the NPSP community for more information.